# Most sensible way to insert DOM element at specific point within ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flexbox

I'm looking to create an podcast player application using AngularJS.

So far, I've got a list of the podcasts available to play, using ng-repeat, which looks like this.

```
<ul ng-controller="list">
  <li ng-repeat="podcast in podcasts" ng-click="startPlaying()">
    <p>{{podcast.created_time | date}}</p>
    <div class="podcast-icon" style="background-image:url('{{podcast.icon}}')">
      <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    </div>
    <h3>{{podcast.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{podcast.duration}}m</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

These are displaying in a responsive flexbox grid, and I want I want the function `startPlaying` to trigger a player to appear, on the row immediately below the clicked item, [similar to Netflix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naKhk.jpg).

I'm confused about how to:

1. Get the index of the `<li>` element **at the end of the row** of the clicked element, given that the grid is responsive and the number of `<li>`s on each row changes with the viewport.
2. Tell angular to insert a new DOM element after a particular index in ng-repeat.

I suppose I could infer the number of `<li>`s per row from the width of the parent, with `window.getComputedStyle(ul).width`, but this seems roundabout. Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can access the index of the li with the following:

```
{{$index}}
```

or even:

```
{{podcasts.indexOf(podcast)}}
```

If you fed that into your click event you could then add an element in the corresponding function, like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="podcast in podcasts" ng-click="startPlaying($index)">
```

But you need to select the correct element so give the li a class:

```
<li class="podcast" ng-repeat="podcast in podcasts" ng-click="startPlaying($index)">
```

Then in your startPlaying function select the element by index and append your element:

```
$scope.startPlaying = function(index) {
  var podcasts = document.getElementsByClassName('podcast')
  var currentPodcast = podcasts[index]
  angular.element(currentPodcast).append('<html></html>');
}
```

Just replace `<html></html>` with your element you want to append.